# How do i check the datatype of my Jarray? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, json, types, json.net

I got a method that receives JProperty's of arrays. 
This can be a simple arrays of strings: ("Img1.png", "Img2.png" ect). or a array with objects:

```
{[{
"id": "1",
"name": "name",
"image": "img1.png"},{
"id": "2",
"name": "name",
"image": "img2.png"},
{
"id": "3",
"name": "name",
"image": "img3.png"
}]}"
```

Within the methods receving the JProperty's different actions need to happen, but i can't get the if-statement to filter the objects too an object event.

This is currently my code:

```
private static void handleArray(JProperty array)
{

    foreach (JArray x in array)
    {
        JTokenType type = x.Type;
        if (type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array with objects!");
        }
        else { 
            foreach (string childrensTokens in x)
              //Array with normal strings
                Console.WriteLine(childrensTokens);
        }
    }
}
```

(the else statement crashes atm because it recieves the objects too.)
Does anyone know how to help me? i tried to get to the childrensTokens but failed.

Comment: `foreach (JArray x in array)`??? there is no `JArray` in `JProperty`

Comment: i'm pretty new with both Json and c#, below i answered how i managed to make it work, but i'm open for feedback ect x]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
 private static void handleArray(JProperty array)
    {
        //voor de gewone array:

        foreach (JArray x in array)
        {
            foreach (var a in x)
                if(a.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Array with objects!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((string) a);
                }


        }
```